# use jolt spec and convert json to json array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a question about transforming a json to jsonArray by jolt spec in apache nifi, my input is :

```
{
  "name": "tom",
  "experience ": [
    {
      "year": "2020",
      "corp": "aaaa"
    },
    {
      "year": "2019",
      "corp": "bbbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the output I need is :

```
[
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "year": "2020",
    "corp": "aaaa"
  },
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "year": "2019",
    "corp": "bbbb"
  }
]
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: I have tried below spec:[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "experence": {
        "*": {
          "year": "experence[&1].year",
          "corp": "experence[&1].corp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]      ,but it can not retrive higher level attribute called "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "experience": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,name)": "[#2].name",
          "*": "[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Note that you have a space in the field `experience`, I removed it from the spec (and the sample input) when testing on the [online Jolt tester](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/).

Comment: Yes, it works and makes my topology running as expected